# How to prove the invertibility of square-matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Recently, I encoutered the following matrix in my work
$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 \text{N}_{0,t_0} & \text{N}_{1,t_0} & \text{N}_{2,t_0} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \text{N}_{1,t_1} & \text{N}_{2,t_1} & \text{N}_{3,t_1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \text{N}_{2,t_2} & \text{N}_{3,t_2} & \text{N}_{4,t_2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{N}_{3,t_3} & \text{N}_{4,t_3} & \text{N}_{5,t_3} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{N}_{4,t_4} & \text{N}_{5,t_4} & \text{N}_{6,t_4} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{N}_{5,t_5} & \text{N}_{6,t_5} & \text{N}_{7,t_5} \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$

where, $N_{i,t_i} + N_{i+1,t_i}+ N_{i+2,t_i}=1, i=0..5$ and $0<N_{i,t_j} <1$

I know it is a banded matrix. To prove the invertibility, I tried to calculate the determinant of this matrix by hand:

$$
\text{N}_{0,\text{t0}} \text{N}_{1,\text{t1}} \text{N}_{2,\text{t2}} \text{N}_{3,\text{t3}} \text{N}_{4,\text{t4}} \text{N}_{5,\text{t5}}+\text{N}_{2,\text{t0}} \text{N}_{1,\text{t1}} \text{N}_{4,\text{t2}} \text{N}_{3,\text{t3}} \text{N}_{6,\text{t4}} \text{N}_{5,\text{t5}}-\text{N}_{1,\text{t0}} \text{N}_{2,\text{t1}} \text{N}_{4,\text{t2}} \text{N}_{3,\text{t3}} \text{N}_{6,\text{t4}} \text{N}_{5,\text{t5}}-\text{N}_{1,\text{t0}} \text{N}_{3,\text{t1}} \text{N}_{2,\text{t2}} \text{N}_{4,\text{t3}} \text{N}_{6,\text{t4}} \text{N}_{5,\text{t5}}-\text{N}_{2,\text{t0}} \text{N}_{1,\text{t1}} \text{N}_{3,\text{t2}} \text{N}_{4,\text{t3}} \text{N}_{6,\text{t4}} \text{N}_{5,\text{t5}}+\text{N}_{1,\text{t0}} \text{N}_{2,\text{t1}} \text{N}_{3,\text{t2}} \text{N}_{4,\text{t3}} \text{N}_{6,\text{t4}} \text{N}_{5,\text{t5}}-\text{N}_{1,\text{t0}} \text{N}_{3,\text{t1}} \text{N}_{2,\text{t2}} \text{N}_{5,\text{t3}} \text{N}_{4,\text{t4}} \text{N}_{6,\text{t5}}-\text{N}_{2,\text{t0}} \text{N}_{1,\text{t1}} \text{N}_{3,\text{t2}} \text{N}_{5,\text{t3}} \text{N}_{4,\text{t4}} \text{N}_{6,\text{t5}}+\text{N}_{1,\text{t0}} \text{N}_{2,\text{t1}} \text{N}_{3,\text{t2}} \text{N}_{5,\text{t3}} \text{N}_{4,\text{t4}} \text{N}_{6,\text{t5}}-\text{N}_{2,\text{t0}} \text{N}_{1,\text{t1}} \text{N}_{4,\text{t2}} \text{N}_{3,\text{t3}} \text{N}_{5,\text{t4}} \text{N}_{6,\text{t5}}+\text{N}_{1,\text{t0}} \text{N}_{2,\text{t1}} \text{N}_{4,\text{t2}} \text{N}_{3,\text{t3}} \text{N}_{5,\text{t4}} \text{N}_{6,\text{t5}}+\text{N}_{1,\text{t0}} \text{N}_{3,\text{t1}} \text{N}_{2,\text{t2}} \text{N}_{4,\text{t3}} \text{N}_{5,\text{t4}} \text{N}_{6,\text{t5}}+\text{N}_{2,\text{t0}} \text{N}_{1,\text{t1}} \text{N}_{3,\text{t2}} \text{N}_{4,\text{t3}} \text{N}_{5,\text{t4}} \text{N}_{6,\text{t5}}-\text{N}_{1,\text{t0}} \text{N}_{2,\text{t1}} \text{N}_{3,\text{t2}} \text{N}_{4,\text{t3}} \text{N}_{5,\text{t4}} \text{N}_{6,\text{t5}}+\text{N}_{0,\text{t0}} \text{N}_{3,\text{t1}} \text{N}_{2,\text{t2}} \text{N}_{5,\text{t3}} \text{N}_{4,\text{t4}} \text{N}_{7,\text{t5}}-\text{N}_{0,\text{t0}} \text{N}_{2,\text{t1}} \text{N}_{3,\text{t2}} \text{N}_{5,\text{t3}} \text{N}_{4,\text{t4}} \text{N}_{7,\text{t5}}-\text{N}_{0,\text{t0}} \text{N}_{2,\text{t1}} \text{N}_{4,\text{t2}} \text{N}_{3,\text{t3}} \text{N}_{5,\text{t4}} \text{N}_{7,\text{t5}}-\text{N}_{0,\text{t0}} \text{N}_{3,\text{t1}} \text{N}_{2,\text{t2}} \text{N}_{4,\text{t3}} \text{N}_{5,\text{t4}} \text{N}_{7,\text{t5}}+\text{N}_{0,\text{t0}} \text{N}_{2,\text{t1}} \text{N}_{3,\text{t2}} \text{N}_{4,\text{t3}} \text{N}_{5,\text{t4}} \text{N}_{7,\text{t5}}+\text{N}_{2,\text{t0}} \text{N}_{3,\text{t1}} \text{N}_{4,\text{t2}} \text{N}_{5,\text{t3}} \text{N}_{6,\text{t4}} \text{N}_{7,\text{t5}}
$$

However, I cannot determine whether or not the result equals to zero from the formula.

So I would like to know is there other method? Thanks.

Comment: Since it is a finite matrix you could use a CAS.

Comment: @Math1000 In fact, the matrix is infinite, I just show a special case of $n=5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all your constraints are convex, the space defined by their cut is convex as well, and therefore connected.

In this case we just need to find one value <0 and one >0, and obtain by the intermediate value theorem that there's a variable assignment so that the matrix is singular.

In the case that I didn't mistype anything, numerical minimization in the given domain gives the value $\approx-1$ for 
{N0t0->7.32901*10^-9,N1t1->4.03786*10^-9,N2t2->3.95874*10^-9,N3t3->3.97883*10^-9,N4t4->3.64508*10^-9,N5t5->3.65982*10^-9,N2t0->5.89946*10^-9,N4t2->5.67405*10^-9,N6t4->3.5052*10^-9,N1t0->1.,N2t1->1.,N3t1->3.45295*10^-9,N4t3->1.,N3t2->1.,N5t3->3.98905*10^-9,N6t5->1.,N5t4->1.,N7t5->3.49373*10^-9}

and numerical maximization gives the value $\approx 1$ for 
{N0t0->0.,N1t1->1.,N2t2->1.11022*10^-16,N3t3->1.,N4t4->0.,N5t5->1.,N2t0->1.,N4t2->1.,N6t4->1.,N1t0->-7.9965*10^-18,N2t1->-2.13382*10^-18,N3t1->-4.31547*10^-17,N4t3->-3.31238*10^-18,N3t2->-7.23892*10^-18,N5t3->-2.09818*10^-18,N6t5->-1.36987*10^-24,N5t4->-8.99898*10^-19,N7t5->-3.42016*10^-18}

The corresponding mathematica input is in [this notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/d6067aa1-487a-473f-a408-84de29b8ab69)